# MySQL root user localhost issue

Tags: mysql, authentication

I have a MySQL server (5.6) running on a virtual Debian box on my local computer. Connecting to MySQL from the localhost command line via the following command worked as expected:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword
```

When originally trying to connect to the virtual machine remotely using MySQL Workbench, I was getting a permission denied message for my root account, which I resolved by commenting out the `bind-address=localhost` directive in the virtual MySQL's `my.cnf` file. Once doing this and rebooting, I was able to connect remotely as expected.

Now though, I am having a different issue - when trying to connect from the command line on the virtual box (i.e. localhost) I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Connecting via the host name, local loopback IP (both IP4 & IP6) and remotely all work:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword -hhostname
mysql -uroot -ppassword -h127.0.0.1
```

Looking at the user table in the database, there are four user accounts for root:

- `root@localhost`
- `root@127.0.0.1`
- `root@::1`
- `root@%`

and they have the correct settings, so everything looks good.

I've run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`, rebooted MySQL, but no solution.

EDIT

Output from `mysql -uroot -ppassword -hlocalhost -ANe"SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();`:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Output from `mysql -uroot -ppassword -hhostname -ANe"SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();`:

```
+----------------+----------------+
| root@hostname | root@% |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Output from `mysql -uroot -ppassword -h127.0.0.1 -ANe"SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();`:

```
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@127.0.0.1 |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: My (version 5.6) MySQL install has a 'localhost' and '%' root user, but doesn't have a '127.0.0.1' entry in the user table.  It seems strange yours is the opposite...  Note: turning off `skip-name-resolve` in my.ini often helps in these cases.  (Hmm on another box, I've got all 3: `localhost`, `::1`, and `127.0.0.1`)

Comment: I am running 5.6 as well (added above) and actually have a fourth account with `::1` as well - just omitted that from the original question. Will try `skip-name-resolve`, but that feels a bit hackish for sure.

Comment: @ebyrob FYI, adding `skip-name-resolve` did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Having deleted `bind-address=localhost`, it is only logical that you need to specify the `-h` parameter. Please explain more what is the problem.

Comment: Please run the following 2 commands: `mysql -uroot -ppassword -hhostname -ANe"SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();"` and `mysql -uroot -ppassword -h127.0.0.1 -ANe"SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` and post the output in the question body.

Comment: @harrymc having commented out that line, specifying, for example, `-hlocalhost` results in the same issue. Uncommenting that line as well, the issue remains.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Added output to the question.